# ANTLR C# Can't find 'IAstRuleReturnScope'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, antlr

I have downloaded the csharp grammar project from here http://antlrcsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/47523, and it runs fine.

But when I add 'output=AST' to the grammar, I get a TON of errors:

[image]

I am admittedly new to ANTLR, so I am not sure how to proceed at this point. I would have assumed this type would have existed in the antlr csharp runtime dll, but obviously not. Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: You might try its latest build instead, where the developers started to use ANTLR 3.3 runtime, which is newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About a year ago I did a project with Antlr and ran into an issue where I got tons of errors. As odd as it sounds but by using an older runtime I got it to work. I think I used a dll that had been compiled for the 2.0 .Net Framework.

I do not remember exactly what the error was or what had actually caused it. All I remember is that it solved the issue. I have no idea if this will help in your situation but it's worth a shot if you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this migrating from a v3.2 script generating from the Java tool to using v3.4 with the dotNet build tools.

I was able to figure out (thx to the documentation that comes with the .net VS integration) that the problem with not getting the right return type was because **a class is only generated if you have a return type on the rule**.  Adding a dummy integer return type to my rules that had no return value cleared that up.

There is a discussion of the rule returns in the C# generator and target in the documentation from the [C# target page at antlr](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases), follow the link at the top of the page and check out section 4.1.1 "Return values"

Answer (score 0):

You are not the first person to have this problem.  The patch at https://github.com/antlr/antlr/pull/1 addresses it by providing the missing file.  Include it in your source and recompile.